# Retrieving Axios Response

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm just new with React JS. I'm trying to replace this below code from local Storage data retrieving from departmentServces.jsx file with function name getAllDepartment

```
  if (localStorage.getItem(KEYS.Dept) == null)
  localStorage.setItem(KEYS.Dept, JSON.stringify([]))
  let Dept = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(KEYS.Dept));

  return Dept.map(x => ({
    ...x
  }))
```

to data retrieving from SQL with below code

```
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:57897/";

  const response = await axios.get("/api/getdepartmentlist");
  
  if (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
    return response.data.map(x => ({
        ...x
    }))
  }
```

but I'm getting error of

> TypeError: array.map is not a function

I'm thinking it was because of this code from Department.jsx that calling the function, but it was correct when used for local storage.

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState(departmentService.getAllDepartment())
```

though I don't know the next step I should do with this.

Here is my code for Department.jsx file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PageHeader from "../PageHeader";
import Controls from "../controls/Controls";
import AccountBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountBox';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import { Paper, makeStyles, TableBody, TableRow, TableCell, Toolbar, InputAdornment } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Search } from "@material-ui/icons";
import * as departmentService from "../Services/departmentService";
import useTable from "../useTable";
import EditOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EditOutlined';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Notification from "../../components/Notification";
import ConfirmDialog from "../../components/ConfirmDialog";
import Popup from "../../components/Popup";
import DepartmentForm from "./DepartmentForm";

import DepartmentIcon from '../../assets/Department.png'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    searchInput: {
        width: '75%'
    },
    newButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '10px'
    }
}))

const headCells = [
    { id: 'code', label: 'Code' },
    { id: 'description', label: 'Description' },
    { id: 'inActive', label: 'Active' },  
    { id: 'actions', label: 'Actions', disableSorting: true }
]

const Department = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [recordForEdit, setRecordForEdit] = useState(null)
    const [records, setRecords] = useState(departmentService.getAllDepartment())
    const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } })
    const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false)
    const [notify, setNotify] = useState({ isOpen: false, message: '', type: '' })
    const [confirmDialog, setConfirmDialog] = useState({ isOpen: false, title: '', subTitle: '' })

    const {
        TblContainer,
        TblHead,
        TblPagination,
        recordsAfterPagingAndSorting
    } = useTable(records, headCells, filterFn);
    
    const handleSearch = e => {
        let target = e.target;
        setFilterFn({
            fn: items => {
                if (target.value === "")
                    return items;
                else
                    return items.filter(x => x.description.toLowerCase().includes(target.value))
            }
        })
    }

    const addOrEdit = (dept, resetForm) => {
        departmentService.saveDepartment(dept)        
        resetForm()
        setRecordForEdit(null)
        setOpenPopup(false)
        setRecords(departmentService.getAllDepartment())
        setNotify({
            isOpen: true,
            message: 'Submitted Successfully',
            type: 'success'
        })
    }
    
    const openInPopup = item => {
        setRecordForEdit(item)
        setOpenPopup(true)
    }

    const onDelete = id => {
        setConfirmDialog({
            ...confirmDialog,
            isOpen: false
        })
        // userService.deleteUser(id);
        // setRecords(userService.getAllUsers())
        setNotify({
            isOpen: true,
            message: 'Deleted Successfully',
            type: 'error'
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <PageHeader
                title="Department Management"
                subTitle="Department Information Maintenance"
                icon={<AccountBoxIcon fontSize="large" />}
            />
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
                <Toolbar>
                <Controls.Input
                        label="Search Department"
                        className={classes.searchInput}
                        InputProps={{
                            startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position="start">
                                <Search />
                            </InputAdornment>)
                        }}
                        onChange={handleSearch}
                    />
                    <Controls.Button
                        text="Add New"
                        variant="outlined"
                        startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                        className={classes.newButton}
                        onClick={() => { setOpenPopup(true); setRecordForEdit(null); }}
                    />
                </Toolbar>
                <TblContainer>
                    <TblHead />
                    <TableBody>
                        {
                            recordsAfterPagingAndSorting().map(item =>
                                (<TableRow key={item.id}>
                                    <TableCell>{item.code}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{item.description}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>{item.inActive}</TableCell>          
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Controls.ActionButton
                                            color="primary"
                                            onClick={() => { openInPopup(item) }}>
                                            <EditOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
                                        </Controls.ActionButton>
                                        <Controls.ActionButton
                                            color="secondary"
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setConfirmDialog({
                                                    isOpen: true,
                                                    title: 'Are you sure to delete this record?',
                                                    subTitle: "You can't undo this operation",
                                                    onConfirm: () => { onDelete(item.id) }
                                                })
                                            }}>
                                            <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
                                        </Controls.ActionButton>
                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>)
                            )
                        }
                    </TableBody>
                </TblContainer>
                <TblPagination />                
            </Paper>
            <Popup
                title="Department Details"
                openPopup={openPopup}
                setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup}
                
            >
                <DepartmentForm
                    recordForEdit={recordForEdit}
                    addOrEdit={addOrEdit} 
                />
            </Popup>
            <Notification
                notify={notify}
                setNotify={setNotify}
            />
            <ConfirmDialog
                confirmDialog={confirmDialog}
                setConfirmDialog={setConfirmDialog}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Department
```

while this is my code for departmentServices.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";

export const saveDepartment = async (values) => {    
    axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:57897/";

    const valuesToSave = { ...values };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/api/savedepartment",
        valuesToSave
      );
      if (response.data.stat === 1) {
        console.log(response.data.message);
      } else {
        console.log(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

export function deleteDepartment(id) {

}

export const getAllDepartment = async (values) => {    
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:57897/";

  const response = await axios.get("/api/getdepartmentlist");
  
  if (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
    return response.data.map(x => ({
        ...x
    }))
  }
}
```

and this is the useTable.jsx I use in the project

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, makeStyles, TablePagination, TableSortLabel } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    table: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
        '& thead th': {
            fontWeight: '600',
            color: theme.palette.primary.main,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
        },
        '& tbody td': {
            fontWeight: '300',
        },
        '& tbody tr:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#fffbf2',
            cursor: 'pointer',
        },
    },
}))

export default function useTable(records, headCells, filterFn) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const pages = [5, 10, 25]
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(pages[page])
    const [order, setOrder] = useState()
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState()

    const TblContainer = props => (
        <Table className={classes.table}>
            {props.children}
        </Table>
    )

    const TblHead = props => {

        const handleSortRequest = cellId => {
            const isAsc = orderBy === cellId && order === "asc";
            setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
            setOrderBy(cellId)
        }

        return (<TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                {
                    headCells.map(headCell => (
                        <TableCell key={headCell.id}
                            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}>
                            {headCell.disableSorting ? headCell.label :
                                <TableSortLabel
                                    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                                    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
                                    onClick={() => { handleSortRequest(headCell.id) }}>
                                    {headCell.label}
                                </TableSortLabel>
                            }
                        </TableCell>))
                }
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>)
    }

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    }

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10))
        setPage(0);
    }

    const TblPagination = () => (<TablePagination
        component="div"
        page={page}
        rowsPerPageOptions={pages}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        count={records.length}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
    />)

    function stableSort(array, comparator) {
        const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
        stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
            const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
            if (order !== 0) return order;
            return a[1] - b[1];
        });
        return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
    }

    function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
        return order === 'desc'
            ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
            : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
    }

    function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
        if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    const recordsAfterPagingAndSorting = () => {
        return stableSort(filterFn.fn(records), getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, (page + 1) * rowsPerPage)
    }

    return {
        TblContainer,
        TblHead,
        TblPagination,
        recordsAfterPagingAndSorting
    }
}
```

Thanks In Advance for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeError: array.map is not a function` would suggest that `array` from `array.map` in `stableSort` is not actually any array. [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) can be used to verify this; e.g.

```
const stabilizedThis = Array.isArray(array)
    ? array.map((el, index) => [el, index])
    : [];
```